# Environment Hub developer edition differences

Tags: org, editions, developer-edition, environment-hub

I've noticed Developer Edition orgs aren't as homogenous as expected. One source of variation is what template they come from. For ISV partners, the options are bifurcated from the very start:

1. Developer Edition from [developer.force.com](https://developer.salesforce.com/en/signup?d=70130000000td6N) (I refer to these as "Vanilla Developer Edition")
2. Partner Developer Edition from [Partner Portal](http://www.salesforce.com/partners/login)
3. Developer Edition from Environment Hub (Organization Type: Release)
4. Developer Edition from Environment Hub (Organization Type: Test)
5. Developer Edition from Environment Hub (Organization Type: Partner)

Until Environment Hub came along, I thought **2** was the best source of truth. But now I'm not even sure that **3** is best bet as I can't deploy Permission Sets containing `ManageCssUsers`  now.

Would the real slim shady please stand up? Which org is best for packages? And which for playing?

[image: environment-hub-one]

[image: environment-hub-two]

Comment: Wha.... my environment hub is missing most of these options!

Comment: Interesting @ca_peterson! Can you link a screenshot?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Woohoo! The Winter '15 release has brought some changes to Environment Hub that clarify this:

The **Create Organization** dialogue now has a **Purpose** field:

[image: purpose]

## For 'Development' purpose there is only one option and this is our guy!

- Partner Developer

[image: development]

> Use a partner development organization to build, package and upload your app. Partner organizations have higher limits and other advanced features and are only available to partners. They are strictly for internal use and should not be shared with customers or prospects.

## For 'Test/Demo' purpose (these guys are nuked after 30 days):

- Partner Enterprise
- Partner Professional
- Partner Group
- Consulting
- Enterprise Edition
- Professional Edition
- Group Edition
- Create using `Trialforce Template ID`

(Mostly documented here in [Partner Development & Test Environments](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Partner_Development_%26_Test_Environments))

[image: test/demo]

> Use a partner test/demo organization for testing your app's compatibility with various editions or to demo your app to prospects. Partner organizations have higher limits and other advanced features and are only available to partners. They are strictly for internal use and should not be shared with customers or prospects.

## For 'Trialforce' purpose (these are template orgs that stick around):

- Enterprise Edition
- Professional Edition

[image: trialforce]

> Use a Trialforce Source Organization (TSO) for creating templates for trial organizations. Trialforce branding is not supported for TSOs you create from here. If you plan to use custom branding for your trials, create the TSO from a Trialforce Management Organization instead.

Comment: Hey @bigassforce, I have developed an application in Dev Org and I would like to know few things, especially on Environment Hub. Where exactly could I create Environment Hub; Do I need to push my entire code into the "Partner Development", from where I am supposed to package and upload it or is it okay if I could upload it from my current Dev org?

Comment: @Sapthagiri Once you have Environment Hub enabled, create a new "Partner Developer Edition" organization, and use that as the single source of truth for all your code and package components. Personally I'd strongly discourage package development in anything other than Partner Developer Edition orgs. (At least for packages intended for public consumption)

Comment: Thank you so much @bigassforce for your valuable information. I was wondering if is okay to enable Environment Hub in the Org **where a package is installed!**. Like, does the Org that is going to be an Environment Hub has to be free from "Manged PAckages" created and "Managed PAckages installed" as well?

Comment: @Sapthagiri that question could distill out some interesting best practises! Totally [ask it](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) :-)

Comment: @bigassforce - you note the Partner Dev & Test Environments doc, but that page doesn't make it clear to me what the difference between Enterprise Edition and Partner Enterprise is. Any suggestions?

Comment: @christiancarter :( i'm don't know

Comment: @bigassforce I guess it's time for me to spin up one of each and find out!

Comment: @bigassforce - I tried em out, my notes are here: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/96253/environment-hub-partner-enterprise-edition-vs-enterprise-edition/96254#96254