# Environment Hub: Partner Enterprise Edition vs. Enterprise Edition

Tags: environment-hub

When spinning up an org for "Test/Demo" in the Environment Hub, there's an option for "Partner Enterprise Edition" and an option for "Enterprise Edition".

[This question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/51863/environment-hub-developer-edition-differences/53843?noredirect=1#comment128458_53843) was updated for the Winter 15 release of Environment Hub, and lays down the different types of Dev and Trial orgs, but it leaves the explanation of "Partner Enterprise Edition" vs "Enterprise Edition" to [this Developerforce article](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Partner_Development_%26_Test_Environments) which is unfortunately silent on the issue.

What is the difference between Partner Enterprise Edition and Enterprise Edition?

Comment: Nice investigation! How about Force.com Sites?

Comment: EE has zero Sites. PEE has 1.

Comment: Whoa, TIL :D :D same for Sandboxes?

Comment: PEE also has 1 Dev Sandbox and 1 Full Sandbox. EE has NO sandboxes. I'm a little shocked by the full!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Having spun up both types of orgs just now, the difference is fairly immediately clear. The Enterprise Edition is your standard 30 day trial, and the Partner Enterprise Edition is a souped up special partner org.

Visually, indeed the PEE org follows the odd pattern of "Setup" being under your user drop down, and not it's own front link. Also, the setup menu is in the same order as PDEs, as opposed to normal DEs.

But the real kicker is in the capabilities.

The EE option gets you, as I said, a standard 30 day trial. It has 5 full Salesforce licenses, no Force.com sites, 5 Content licenses, 5 Apex Mobile licenses, and 5 Marketing user licenses.

The PEE option gets you a WHOLE LOT MORE.

It has 20 EE licenses, that expire in 3 years. It has another 20 Platform licenses, and all the various Portal, Community, and feature licenses you expect from a new partner dev org or org. It even has analytics cloud.

PEE also has 1 Dev Sandbox and 1 Full Sandbox. EE has NO sandboxes.

If you want to see what your app will look like in a brand new trial, go for EE. But if you want to do demos, DEFINITELY opt for PEE.

Comment: I get 1 year expiration on PEE. Is there a way to extend it?