# Salesforce org showing 55 days remaining message

Tags: org

I have sfdc org which is showing 55 days remaining message on top. generally if we have enterprise trial org it expired in 30 days and if we have developer org it never expires until it is not used for specified time. Also i am not able to see system overview option in the left search option.
Check the screenshot and it would be great if you can guide me on this.[image]

Comment: what type of org it is?

Comment: Its on na16 so its either enterprise org or dev org, Right?

Answer (score 2):

Actually Partner enterprise edition get different expire time.Probably around 1-3(My results show 1 year.Not sure what is exact but it is more than 30 days atleast) years expiration time.So the thing to check here is that if this org is generated from environment hub as an partner enterprise edition.

To check this you can go in setup->company information

[image: Check env hub info]

See [this link](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/96253/environment-hub-partner-enterprise-edition-vs-enterprise-edition) for more information.

**Edit:**

I just spun partner enterprise edition org.I'm not sure how to find the expiration date actually but under company information section for all licenses i'm seeing **a date one year later from today for expiration**.So i think this is it.

Comment: Also, Sales can choose to modify the Trial Expiration Date to any time they like. They'll usually do this if they're trying to close a deal and the prospect just needs more time. Or salesforce might have been running a promotion with special orgs with a greater expiration date.