# Why new Developer Orgs spun with Environment Hub now have Status=Trial and do expire? I while ago it was Status=Free without expiration

Tags: isv, developer-edition, partner, org, environment-hub

Today I had to spin some new DE orgs via the Environment Hub. I've done this often before and I thought to know the process.

But I was shocked after taken a closer look on the orgs, which have been provisioned by Salesforce as you can see here:

[image]

I highlighted the last known-good line green. **Status** was *Free* and **Org Expiration Date** was *empty*. Fine! That's what we need.

But now watch the red line: **Status** seems to be *Trial* and **Org Expiration Date** is *2017*. This will result into the loss of several man-years of development-work at the time the org will expire. At this time my only explanation is, that this could be a bug in Salesforces' spinning procedure or org-template. I can't imagine that this behavior is on purpose or does make sense in any way.

I created the orgs below the red line exactly the same as I've done with the orgs above the green line. See here:

[image]

Reviewing [Environment Hub developer edition differences](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/51863/environment-hub-developer-edition-differences) I think how I fill in this form **was** and **still is** the intended way it should be done, right?

**Question**

Did anyone else has witnessed this behavior, too? Does anyone know the steps to take to restore the previous behavior? Has anyone contacted the Salesforce Support on that matter and if so, how was the response?

I'm asking here because logging a ticket requires a lot time for babysitting of the case, the support reps usually try to call me and I'm not available by phone. Also it helps a lot if you can tell the support-guys exactly what you want them to do (i. e. to tell them the solution and prevent them from doing time-consuming researches with open outcome and verbose communication-ping-pong)

**So any hint (as small it might be) would help me a lot to understand what is going on here an which steps I need to take.**

Comment: In parallel I've opened a case (14137609) at the support.

Comment: Maybe the most interesting question is: am I the only one with this behavior? Can anyone reproduce it? Can anyone still create PDEs without expiration date? If I'm the only one, sure the problem is related to my Hub-Org. I can't really test this, since that Org is the only one with Environment Hub installed to which I have access to.

Comment: I confirm that behaviour. Today created PDE has expiration date set to 7/7/2017. http://prntscr.com/bphqid

Comment: Thanks @DenisPereverzev - now that we know it's not a one-time-occurrence, we have to hope, that someone from Salesforce will start working on case 14137609 and help us to go back to normal again. This is a very serious bug IMO. If others are going to raise own cases, please refer to my case number to combine the momentum.

Comment: Also faced same issue with Environment Hub. Going to post a case

Comment: My case 14137609 is now open for 14 days at the support. No reply at all so far and case status is still "New". Today I've escalated the case. Has anyone of you got any feedback?

Comment: @UweHeim According to the [official documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/environment_hub_faq_org_types.htm) it should never expire. Any updates so far?

Comment: @Basti only that I have logged a ticket and support fixed it. It was a simple bug I suppose. Did not repeat since than, and we are creating lots of Orgs frequently.

Comment: Just an inkling, but Salesforce is probably trying to move away from Developer Editions in favour of Trailhead Playgrounds and Scratch Orgs. It's surely more cost effective to have time-limited orgs than continuing to hand out free mini-orgs in the form of the old-fashioned Dev Editions. Scratch Orgs -
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_scratch_orgs.htm Trailhead Playground -
https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/trailhead_playground_management/create-a-trailhead-playground

Answer (score 1):

July 2020 update: the DE orgs spin up as expected from the Env Hub.  Listed as Free with no expiry date.